# Safari 6 freezing

Tags: safari, performance

I've recently upgraded to Safari 6 in Lion and I'm seeing some pages freeze: I cannot scroll down and sometimes cannot click on anything. Safari is still alive and working but the freeze cannot be fixed by reloading the page.

A short Google session turned up a few comments about this being a problem with Javascript (apparently Safari is using a new engine). Sure enough, if I disable Javascript (using the Debug menu), then the freeze is gone after reloading the page. However, this is very inconvenient.

Does this happen to others?
Does anyone have a better fix?

Comment: I ended up getting feed up with safari, and moving to chrome. I've enjoy it much more.

Comment: @demure, yeah... I like Safari 5 just fine and Safari 6 seemed just as fine, until it began acting up.

Comment: Sorry, no solution, I ended up not using it till mom apple comes with a clean version.

Comment: Here is a discussion at Apple forums, but with no solution: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4145775.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve upgraded to Safari 6.1.1 and till now it’s behaving very well, no freezes.

Comment: The same freezes have started again, out of the blue, now with Safari 6.1.4...